# Memory leak issue in (Scala + Akka HTTP) micro service

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, akka-http

I have deployed my micro services into docker container on AWS server which is written using Akka-HTTP(https://github.com/theiterators/akka-http-microservice) and Scala. I am facing memory leak issues & performance problems once I deployed the service to AWS server.

I have noticed that the memory usage increased when server getting more number of requests(like 340mb, 410mb, 422mb...) & depends on load, then it automatically came down to the normal state (230mb). But Memory usage keeps on increasing when server getting more number of requests and it failed to release unused memory even after CPU usage came to the normal stage and finally it reached its maximum (512mb) and crashed.

We can avoid this if it cleared the unused memory/resources properly. JVM should handle the memory usage by itself using Garbage collectors. But it failed to clear unwanted memory(objects) once the request is processed. I am using the below code to clear the Akka.HTTP actor objects.

```
try {
    <-- code block -->
} catch {
case e: Exception =>
    sys.addShutdownHook(system.shutdown())
} finally {
    sys.addShutdownHook(system.shutdown())
}
```

How can I remove unused memory/resources immediately after the execution process has been completed?

Please provide us a solution/way to resolve this problem as soon as possible as it is a very critical problem for us?

Comment: It's very hard (impossible?) to give a meaningful answer to this question. Please consider creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as per SO suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 512mb sounds like a really small heap for running a scala web service.
Try giving it more heap (say, 2g), and seeing if that solves your problem

Comment: What version of akka-http was that? We fixed a few memory leaks over the last year.

Comment: @jrudolph We are using akka-http version 2.4.3 to develop our microservices.

Comment: Then try to update to the latest akka-http 10.0.6 and akka 2.4.18

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should remove the code that is supposed to solve your problem.

BTW if you do it on each request you can spoil all the memory with these shutdown hooks.